# iOS Objective-C Display PNG Image In Custom Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm creating a custom framework. Previously in the framework we would download an image and use that to display in a button:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets/home.png"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *homeButton = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
self.rewardsCenterButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[homeButton imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                            target:self
                                            action: @selector(backToRewardsCenter:)];
```

However, in reviewing this we determined that this isn't good to have as a synchronous call so I'd like to add this PNG to the framework itself.

I've been able to do this by adding the image and ensuring it's included in the copy bundle resources Build Phase. With this set the image gets added in the universal framework output:

[image]

However, when I attempt to add this in code, it doesn't seem to show up. Also, when I add the framework in a project, I don't see the image being included, just the headers:

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/TheoremReachSDK.framework/home.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    UIImage *homeButton = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

And:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[TheoremReach class]];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"home" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *homeButton = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

And:

```
UIImage *homeButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
```

But none of those display anything. Any idea what I need to do to get the image to display?

Comment: what bundle ID did you give to your framework?

Comment: Not sure - how would I see that? I'm not sure I set that...

Comment: look in your bundle's Info.plist file

Comment: In the framework it's set to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing NSBundle isn't finding the framework via the call to:

```
[NSBundle bundleForClass:[TheoremReach class]]
```

Try giving your framework an explicit bundle ID, e.g.: `com.theoremreach.sdk`, clean your projects and then rebuild.

You can then use code like this to fetch and display your image:

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = @"com.theoremreach.sdk";
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:bundleIdentifier];
if(bundle != nil) {
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"home" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *homeButtonImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if(homeButtonImage != nil) {
        self.rewardsCenterButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[homeButtonImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                           target:self
                                           action: @selector(backToRewardsCenter:)];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"couldn't find home button image in bundle");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"could not find bundle with identifier %@", bundleIdentifier);
}
```

Comment: This definitely seems like it should be working, but I continually see that it couldn't find the bundle with the identifier `com.theoremreach.sdk` despite cleaning, building and completely restarting Xcode :(

Comment: Look in the Info.plist file in framework within your compiled app (i.e. from the Products folder of your app project), does the bundle ID appear there?

Comment: Doesn't appear to.  But I'm also using sublime text after `cd`'ing into the .app and most of the file seems encoded. I don't see any of the framework's stuff in this plist

Comment: If you double click the Info.plist file, it should open in the Xcode editor.  My current thinking is that the bundle ID you think you applied didn't actually make it into the framework embedded in the finished product.

Comment: so it isn't an embedded framework, it's just a framework - perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Take a look within the built app in the Products folder.  Do you see your framework there?  Or do you see your "home.png" file anywhere within any of that product's subfolders?  If not, you might need to add the framework via an "Embed Framework" step in your app's Build Phases, so that way resources can be found and picked up.